# Jquery: Button to go through dropdown values and back to beginning

Tags: jquery, html, button, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list. I want to change the value with a button click. So it should go through all the values until the end, and then just go back to the beginning.

Also for every time the button is clicked, it should change the innerHTML.

I dont know if it's possible.

So this is my HTML for the dropdown:

```
<div id="masterChart_length" class="dataTables_length">
<label>Show 
<select size="1" name="masterChart_length" aria-controls="masterChart">
<option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="50">50</option>
<option value="-1">All</option>
</select> 
entries</label>
</div>
```

This is the html for the button to use:

```
<button type="button" id="change-dropdown" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">10</button>
```

I found this post [Looping through selected values in multiple select combobox JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691117/looping-through-selected-values-in-multiple-select-combobox-jquery)

But it displays all the values using this Jquery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#change-dropdown').click(function() {
        $('#masterChart_length > :selected').each(function() {
            alert($(this).value());   // using text() here, because the 
        });                          // options have no value..?
    });
});
```

I am using Datatables by the way and I want to change how the number of entries dropdown works, with just a button click.

Any suggestions or help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#change-dropdown').click(function() {        
        $('#masterChart_length :selected').each(function() {            
            var curElement = $(this).text();   // using text() here, because the                
            var nextElement = $(this).next();
            var nextElementText = $.trim(nextElement.text());
            if(nextElementText!=''){
            $(curElement).removeAttr('selected');
            $(nextElement).attr('selected',true);
            }else{
                //$(this).removeAttr('selected'); // reset here
                $('#masterChart_length option:first-child').attr("selected", "selected");
            }
        }); // options have no value..?     
        });
    });
```

Updated answer below with code changes and it also changes the text of button

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('#change-dropdown').click(function() {
        var oSelectBoxName = '#masterChart_length';
        var oSelectBox = $(oSelectBoxName+' :selected');
        var curElement = oSelectBox.text();   // using text() here, because the                 
        var nextElement = oSelectBox.next();

        var nextElementText = $.trim(nextElement.text());
        if(nextElementText!=''){
            $(this).html(nextElement.text());
            $(curElement).removeAttr('selected');
            $(nextElement).attr('selected',true);
        }else{
            var ofirstElement = $(oSelectBoxName+' option:first-child');
            $(this).html(ofirstElement.text());
            ofirstElement.attr("selected", "selected");// reset here
        }                   
    });
});
```

});

Comment: Can you maybe put this in a jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Please note that `HTML` `SELELECT` must have `id="masterChart_length"` currently it is set in name attribute

Comment: Cool, it works but I need to go back to the beginning, any idea?

Comment: @msbodetti it should go to beginning with current code... `ELSE` is written fot that... is it not working?

Comment: @msbodetti Beginning means it should go to the first option with text `10` ... right?

Comment: Ah it works now thank you :) is there also a way to change the button html() according to the dropdown html() http://jsfiddle.net/sBvjE/3/

Comment: @msbodetti this can be done by setting text value of `buttonElement.html(<select text>)`

Comment: I did that http://jsfiddle.net/sBvjE/4/ but it's skipping the first one.. Any suggestions?

Comment: @msbodetti have a look into jsfiddler here http://jsfiddle.net/WFmqz/1/ ... lot of changes in code too :)

Comment: This doesn't help, just put it into my website but it's only changing the text not the actual value!

Comment: @msbodetti  Could you please explain it more? to get the value you can use `var oSelectBoxName = '#masterChart_length'; var oVal = $(oSelectBoxName+' :selected').val(); console.log(oVal);`

Comment: sorry made a mistake in my html, but I got it working thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(function($) {
 $('#change-dropdown').click(function() {
   $("#master_chartlength option:selected").removeAttr("selected").next().attr("selected","selected");
 });
});
```

I supposed you wanted the value to keep changing (next after next) each time that button was clicked

for looping back (if needed) you can add the condition

```
if($("#master_chartlength option:selected").is(":last-child"))
   $("#master_chartlength option:first").attr("selected","selected");
```

Comment: I cant seem to get it to work in this fiddle using your code: http://jsfiddle.net/eT2dJ/

Comment: @msbodetti Remove `this` from your selector. This is because the `select` isn't actually child of `this`.

Comment: @Puuskis yes I had edited that out later, first I had added that event at select onchange and was selecting( option:selected, this), thanks

Comment: Yay it works! But it's skipping the last option "All". http://jsfiddle.net/eT2dJ/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#change-dropdown').click(function() {
    var option = $("#masterChart_length option:selected");
    $(option).next().attr("selected","selected");
    $(option).removeAttr("selected");
});
```